# Error joining four view tables with non homogeneous attributes

Tags: mysql

We have been trying to join three view tables together based on different attributes and we have been getting a few errors saying that there are duplicates.
This is what our code looks like:

```
create view AllScores as 
select players.*, topattacker.*, topkeepers.*, topmidfielders.*, topdefenders.* 
from players 
inner join topattacker on topattacker.PL_ID = players.PL_ID
inner join topdefenders on topdefenders.PL_ID = players.PL_ID
inner join topkeepers on topkeepers.PL_ID = players.PL_ID 
inner join topmidfielders on topmidfielders.PL_ID = players.PL_ID
where players.PL_ID = topattacker.PL_ID and 
players.PL_ID = topdefenders.PL_ID and 
players.PL_ID = topkeepers.PL_ID and 
players.PL_ID = topmidfielders.PL_ID 
group by players.PL_ID
```

Comment: seems 5 table not 3

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: don't use the `.*` list all the field names -- you will see what the dups are quickly

Comment: it still gives us an error despite removing the .*

Comment: @GeorgesElias what is the select list when you remove the .*?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that some of the tables have the same name.  For example you have `players.PL_ID` and `topattacker.PL_ID`.

Since you are using `.*` you are getting all the PL_IDs from all tables.  You can't have more than one column with the same name on this platform.

To solve remove all `.*` and list out each column you need.

This is advisable in almost every case except an ad-hoc query anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need  explict column name in select and not table.*

```
create view AllScores as 
select disctint  p.col1, p.col2,  ... 
  , a,col1, a.col2, ....
  , k.col1, k.col2, ....
  , f.col1, f.col2 ...
  , d.col1, d.col2  , ..... 
from players p
inner join topattacker  a on a.PL_ID = p.PL_ID 
inner join topdefenders  d on d.PL_ID = a.PL_ID 
inner join topkeepers on  k k.PL_ID = p.PL_ID 
inner join topmidfielders f  on f.PL_ID = p.PL_ID
```

and if you don't use aggreagtion function you don't need  group by but distinct  also you don't need  where when you have already a equivalent join condition